# jQuery wildcard selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, wildcard

I want to select all the elements that have attribute starting with `data-something-`

For example

```
<span data-something-random="test">span 1</span>
<span data-nope="nope">span 2</span>
<span data-something-else="another test">span 3</span>
```

From the above example, I want to select span 1 and span 3.

I've tried

```
$('*[$data-validate]')
```

But it didn't work.

Alternative ways involving jQuery method instead of pseudo selectors are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('*').filter(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            data = that.data();
        for (var a in data){
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(a)){
                return /^something/.test(a);
            }
        }
    }).css('color','red');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9Wm9w/).

Edited to offer a simple jQuery plugin that achieves the same, requiring you pass in a regular expression:

```
$.fn.hasAttrMatching = function (expr) {
    var reg, data;
    if (!expr) {
        return this;
    } else {
        if (typeof expr === 'string') {
            reg = new RegExp(expr);
        } else if (typeof expr === 'object' && expr.test) {
            reg = expr;
        }
        return this.filter(function () {
            data = $(this).data();
            for (var a in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
                    return reg.test(a);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9Wm9w/3).

This can be called as follows,  using a *literal* regular expression:

[$('body, body *').hasAttrMatching(/^something/).css('color', 'red');](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9Wm9w/3/)

Using a string representation of a regular expression:

[`$('body, body *').hasAttrMatching('^something').css('color', 'red');`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9Wm9w/4/)

It seems somewhat obvious to remind you, at this point, but if no expression is passed in (as either a regex literal or a string) then no filtering will occur, the plugin will return the same elements it received, to illustrate:

[`$('body, body *').hasAttrMatching().css('color', 'red');`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9Wm9w/5/)

Which, as you can see in the linked demo, colours *all* elements matched by the original selector.

References:

- Plain JavaScript:

  - [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
  - [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
  - [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 3):

You can't select attributes that way, the left-hand-side needs to be a full attribute and you can only use the $= to query its contents. FYI the * is not required.

```
$('[data-something-random^=te]')
```

You can select both attributes and add them together if you want:

```
$('[data-something-random]').add('[data-something-else]');
```

Doing what you want is possible but I don't think there is out of the box support in jQuery though. A better solution would probably be to add a class or other attribute to the elements and check them.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/csTaw/1/)

Comment: Not a viable solution in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// Get all the apan's that starts with data-something
var $span = $('span').filter(function(index){
    var data = $(this).data();
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(data)) {
        var result = false;
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {              
            result = (key.search(/^something/) != -1);
        });
        return result;
    }
    else return false;
});

// Work with the two span's for above example
$span.each(function () {

   // Your code goes here...
})
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uT6AA/)

Comment: Works great.
--Don't stop the party-- :D

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the selector capabilities in jQuery:

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    withAttrLike: function(elem, _, m) {
        var attrs = elem.attributes, pattern = new RegExp(m[3]);
        for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; ++i)
            if (pattern.test(attrs[i].name))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now you can write:

```
$("div:withAttrLike('^data-something')").hide();
```

The "argument" to the new selector expression is a regexp; somewhat cryptically, that's available in the selector's implementation as `m[3]` (which I think is the result of a regex match that parses the selector expressions in the guts of Sizzle).  The code instantiates a regex and uses it to test the attribute names.

Answer (score -1):

Since you can't select by data attribute names alone (as they are the left-hand side), one possible approach could add a `name` attribute on your spans to logically group the data attributes, and then select by the `name` attribute.

HTML:

```
<span name=data-something-group data-something-random="test">span 1</span>
<span name=data-nope data-nope="nope">span 2</span>
<span name=data-something-group data-something-else="again">span 3</span>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('[name^="data-something-group"])
```

Comment: @bukfixart: How do you know?

Comment: No, it works when 'name' is attribute name and 'value' is attribute value
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: This will be much faster than manually iterating all elements. However, `span` elements can't have the `name` attribute. Instead, I would use the `class` attribute or another `data-*` custom attribute.